# このMySQLのクエリをActiveRecordっぽく書くには

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

ブログの投稿の数を日毎にカウントして集計をとりたいのですが、グループの書き方が冗長になってしまっています。

現在はこのクエリで思うような結果が得られているのですが、もう少しActiveRecordっぽく書くことは出来ませんか?
`Post.group('DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, "+00:00","+09:00"), "%Y/%m/%d")').count`

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord ではそこまでの抽象化機能は持っていないので、あきらめてSQL文をべた書きするしかないと思います。

`where` メソッドでは AREL の `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction` を使って無理矢理Rubyの世界だけで完結できますが、現在のところ `group` では利用できないようです。

一見動きそうだけど**動かない**コード:

```
Post.group(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("DATE_FORMAT", [
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("CONVERT_TZ", [
      Post.arel_table[:created_at],
      "+00:00",
      "+09:00"
    ]),
    "%Y/%m/%d"
  ])
).count
```